# How do I invoke a method with array parameter in java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, invocation

I have an assignment in which I have to perform operations on array in Java, I have to make separate functions of each operation, which I will write but I can not figure out how to invoke a method with array parametres. I usually program in c++ but this assignment is in java. If any of you can help me, I'd be really thankful. :)

```
public class HelloJava {
    static void inpoot() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int[10];

        System.out.println("Please enter 10 numbers ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    static void outpoot(int[] numbers) {
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
                System.out.println(numbers[i]); 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inpoot();
        outpoot(numbers); //can not find the symbol
    }
}
```

Comment: Like so: `outpoot(numbers)` but where is the `numbers` array supposed to come from?

Comment: from the user in inpoot() function.

Comment: If you program in C++, you should already know that invoking methods that take an array as a parameter is exactly the same.

Comment: So in C++ you pass to a function a variable declared localy somewhere else, I see...

Comment: I agree, I was not at all correct that's why I asked a question here. You guys don't have to be mean. I was just asking for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `inpoot` method has to return the `int[]` array, and then you pass it to `outpoot` as a parameter:

```
public class HelloJava {    
    static int[] inpoot() { // this method has to return int[]
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int[10];

        System.out.println("Please enter 10 numbers ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        return numbers; // return array here
    }

    static void outpoot(int[] numbers) {
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
            System.out.println(numbers[i]); 
        }
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = inpoot(); // get the returned array
        outpoot(numbers); // and pass it to outpoot
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you call outpoot it should be
    outpoot (numbers);

Comment: it doesn't work, I've tried. The "can not find the symbol" error appears.

Comment: It's because numbers is a local variable declared in the inpoot method. It's out of scope I'm the main method

Comment: And that's what I'm asking, how do I pass the numbers array there. I mean, what do I do to make it take the array from inpoot and pass it in the outpoot call in main function.

Comment: You could make the inpoot method return the array instead of a void. And then in the main method pass it in as a param.